# Impression Tracking - How Do I Structure in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to include impression tracking with if else statements. how do i structure it? The content is in the html, it is not pulling in a content block.

e.g.

```
%%[IF @Category == 'Home' THEN]%%
    content for home.
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Sport' THEN]%%
    <p> content for sport </p>
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Electronics' THEN]%%
```

Where do the `%%=BeginImpressionRegion("Home")=%%` and `%%=EndImpressionRegion("Home")=%%` go?

Would it be

```
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("Home")=%%

%%[IF @Category == 'Home' THEN]%%
    content for home.
    %%=EndImpressionRegion("Home")=%%
    %%=BeginImpressionRegion("Sport")=%%
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Sport' THEN]%%
    <p> content for sport </p> 
    %%=EndImpressionRegion("Sport")=%%

    %%=BeginImpressionRegion("Electronics")=%%
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Electronics' THEN]%% 
    %%=EndImpressionRegion("Electronics")=%%
```

Also, does impression tracking have to be specifically switched on in an SFMC account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the Impression Region calls within the IFs. That way you can dynamically change the name.

```
%%[IF @Category == 'Home' THEN BeginImpressionRegion("Home")
]%%
    <p>content for home.<p>
    %%=EndImpressionRegion("Home")=%%

%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Sport' THEN  BeginImpressionRegion("Sport")]%%
    <p> content for sports </p>
    %%=EndImpressionRegion("Sport")=%%


%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Electronics' THEN BeginImpressionRegion("Electronics")]%% 

        <p> content for electronics </p> 
        %%=EndImpressionRegion("Electronics")=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

As [David Devoy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/21264/david-devoy) points out, you need to contact Support to enable this feature in your account.

Comment: Ah ok, so there will be a link within each content area, but they won't contain ampscript. It's basically dynamic content and I wanted to track each of 3 variants.

Comment: Ok makes sense how many links would be in each content block?

Comment: Just the one in each of the 3 blocks. But they are simple hrefs. What i wanted to do was generate a reports showing the clicks of each variant. At the moment they are all lumped together in a triggered send report

Comment: Why do you call the impression regions from within the if statements? That way you can also dynamically change their names

Comment: Yeah I would have done that, but it's an existing build that I am trying to adapt. There are no content blocks, its all within the html.

Comment: You do need to contact support to enable the impression region business rules.  Also request that they include the impression region reports.

Comment: Will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your variable in BeginImpressionRegion function. It is slightly tricky, but indeed doable:

```ampscript
%=TreatAsContent(concat("%","%=BeginImpressionRegion('",@Category,"')=%","%"))=%%
%%[IF @Category == 'Home' THEN]%%
     <p>content for home</p>
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Sport' THEN]%%
     <p>content for sport</p> 
%%[ELSEIF @Category == 'Electronics' THEN]%% 
     <p>content for electronics</p> 
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
%%=EndImpressionRegion()=%%
```

This solution will reduce the code you need to maintain, as it will automatically create an impression region with the same name as your category. You don't need to provide the name of impression region in the `EndImpressionRegion()` function. There is the option of providing a boolean value of 1: `EndImpressionRegion(1)`, which will close ALL previously opened impression regions. The default is 0/false, which will only close the last opened region.

You can read this article containing more details on how to [work with Impression Region Tracking in Salesforce Marketing Cloud](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/reporting/impression-tracking-in-marketing-cloud/).